# AutoFilter with multiple criteria using dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter column with multiple criteria using an array.
I think it can be done using a **Dictionary** like the accepted answer of this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76152460/autofilter-for-cells-contains-exactly-specific-number).
I adapted the code a little , But I got (Type Mismatch error)  at this line:

`If Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0) Then`

**Note**: If there is another answer (without using a helper column) is highly welcomed.

```
Sub AutoFilter_With_Multiple_Criteria()

    Const filter_Column As Long = 2
    Const filter_Delimiter As String = " "
    
    Dim filter_Criteria() As Variant
    filter_Criteria = Array("Cathodic Protection", "C.P", "Riser")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1) 'the source range (UsedRange except the first Row)

    Dim rCount As Long, arr() As Variant
    rCount = rg.Rows.count - 1
    arr = rg.Columns(filter_Column).Resize(rCount).Offset(1).value      'Write the values from criteria column to an array.
        
    Dim dict As New Dictionary                                    'Write the matching strings to the keys (a 1D array) of a dictionary.
    
    Dim subStrings() As String, r As Long, i As Long, rStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount                                           'Loop through the elements of the array.
        rStr = arr(r, 1)                                          'Convert the current value to a string and store it in a variable.
        If Len(rStr) > 0 Then                                     'is not blank
           subStrings = Split(rStr, filter_Delimiter)                 'Split the string into an array.
            For i = 0 To UBound(filter_Criteria)
              If Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0) Then
                If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then
                    dict(rStr) = Empty
                End If
              End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
    
    If dict.count > 0 Then
        rg.AutoFilter Field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did IsNumeric not work from what VBasic used in his question to your previous question?

Comment: `Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0)` will raise an error (even not a fatal one) if used in your way. That's why you should use a variant variable to check it after receiving the value/error, or simpler, directly check against the error (`If `IsNumeric()`, or `If Not Iserror()`)...

Comment: @FaneDuru , I tried your suggestion `If Not IsError` , the error has been disappeared, But, the result of AutoFilter did not include any cell contains this string "`Cathodic Protection`" , I know it has a space.

Comment: This only means that the string in the cell(s) you need to be visible, is  not identic with the one in the array. The third parameter of the `Match` method means **exact match**...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,Should I post a new question or it can be adapted on my answer?

Comment: I am driving...

Comment: So, do you want checking if one of the array strings is contained in the respective cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to filter by cells **containing** any of the criteria array element, please try the next adapted code. It assumes that you need to filter on the first column (A:A):

```
Sub AutoFilter_With_Multiple_Criteria()

    Const filter_Column As Long = 1 'column A:A
    
    Dim filter_Criteria() As Variant: filter_Criteria = Array("*Cathodic Protection*", "*C.P*", "*Riser*") 'changed array to avoid exact matches!
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.rows.count - 1).Offset(1) 'the source range (UsedRange except the first Row)

    Dim rCount As Long, arr() As Variant, El
    rCount = rg.rows.count - 1
    arr = rg.Columns(filter_Column).Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value     'Write the values from criteria column to an array.
        
    Dim dict As New scripting.Dictionary                               'Write the matching strings to the keys (a 1D array) of a dictionary.
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount                                               'Loop through the elements of the array.
        If Len(arr(r, 1)) > 0 Then                                    'is not blank
            For Each El In filter_Criteria
                If arr(r, 1) Like El Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString: Exit For
            Next El
        End If
    Next r
    
    If dict.count > 0 Then
        rg.AutoFilter field:=filter_Column, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues   'use the keys of the dictionary (a 1D array) as a Criteria
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

If you need the opposite (to filter what does not match any array element, you should change the dictionary loading iteration in the next way:

```
Dim boolFound as Boolean

    For r = 1 To rCount                                           
        If Len(arr(r, 1)) > 0 Then                               
            boolFound = False
            For Each El In filter_Criteria
                If arr(r, 1) Like El Then boolFound = True: Exit For
           Next El
           If Not boolFound Then dict(CStr(arr(r, 1))) = vbNullString 'CStr used in case of numeric values, which be converted to string in order to be taken in consideration...
        End If
    Next r
    Debug.Print Join(dict.keys, "|"): Stop 'just to see the new built array...
```

Comment: @Soma OK, let us take it point by point. 1. Do you want filtering the cells **containing** one or more array strings, as stated? 2. Did you use the code as it is? 3. Is the column to be filtered the first one (A:A)? If not, did you adapt the `filter_Column` value? 4. Please, show some examples of "irrelevant cells included on the result".

Comment: 1. yes I want filtering the cells **containing** one or more array strings ,But consider every array element is a unit word , e,g  I need cells that contain "`Cathodic Protection`" in the same order ("`*Cathodic+Space+Protection*`). 2. Yes I have used your code as it is, But I adapted `filter_Column =2` column B:B. 4. for my work privacy issue , I can not show the irrelevant cells .

Comment: @Soma Without seeing the respective irrelevant cells content I am afraid I cannot help, because I cannot understand what happens. I tested the above code for all cases and it worked as it should. At least, what I could understand it should...

Comment: I tried on a dummy sheet and the same problem, I think there is a misunderstanding for my issue ( with no offence at all). Anyhow I am searching for a web-site to upload the dummy file and send link for you back.

Comment: @Soma It was an obvious mistake in the code, sorry... I made more tests (doing also something else) and posted a wrong `Sub` version. Your testing workbook to be downloaded from [here](https://easyupload.io/ibqhpf)...

Comment: **Excellent, I tried the new code and it works flawlessly**, in fact you provided me with a solution to overcome limitation of inbuilt excel AutoFilter ( I mean excel provide only two criteria)

Comment: **Also, you latest code is very fast** , I tried on my real dataset and it toke **0.03** seconds to finish.

Comment: Please, I do not understand, How the non blank keys are added to the Dictionary? the dictionary `dict` has been created with empty keys and later you just used this part `dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString` , is there a code golf in your code?

Comment: @Soma Sorry for the late presence here. I am rather busy in this period... I corrected the ending `End If`. I rapidly copied a part from my code and looked to be OK... If you do not need to use the case of already existing key, **`Scripting.Dictionary` is clever enough to check the existence instead of you and creates new keys ONLY IF THEY DO NOT EXIST**.  Checking for the key existence means a useless condition which also consumes some microseconds... :) But only in these circumstances, when the code must not do anything in case of an existing key.

Comment: Sorry for asking another info. Please, If I need to do the opposite, meaning by filtering out all `filter_Criteria` and show the cells not containing any element of it. I tried to use `If Not arr(r, 1) Like El Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString` but it has no effect at all, I also tried to use instr function `If InStr(arr(r, 1), El) = 0 Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString` but also has no effect.

Comment: @Soma The logic you tried is wrong... You should create a boolean variable which to be made as true during (the same) iteration, without using `dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString`. Before the check you must have `boolFound = false`. Then checking after iteration if the respective variable is false `Then dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString`. No time now to open Excel...

Comment: @Soma I opened Excel and edited my answer showing what I meant in the above comment...

Comment: Welcome Back. In most of your answers you used `""` for null string, but in this case you used `vbNullString`. Is there a significant difference between them or it is a matter of other something?

Comment: @Waleed No, there is no difference (in terms of value). You can check it simple using `Debug.Print vbNullString = ""`. I usually use `""` because is a shorter string and it looks (for me, at least) more eloquent when wanting to check if the value of a cell, array element etc. is empty. In case of a `Dictionary` key, using `""` may confuse the non experimented user, I think. So, expressly using `vbNullString` looks more eloquent (for me)...

Comment: also, Is **Dictionary** accepts only values of string type? because I have used this code but it did not work correctly `dict(arr(r, 1)) = ""` but when I used **Cstr** function then it works correctly `dict(CStr(arr(r, 1))) = ""`

Comment: @Waleed Such a dictionary accepts **all kind of variables**, objects inclusive. What happened in your case is something **connected to the context you try it**. If you declare `i As Long` and try `For i = 1 to 3` `dict(i) =""` `Next i` followed by `Debug.print join(dict.keys, "|")`, it will return `1|2|3`. If you use it in an environment requiring a string, it must be a string, otherwise it accepts even a range as key...

Comment: I remember that you said one a day `Array` does not work with **filtered Range**, I noticed yesterday that your code works perfectly on my filtered range (sure I already deleted If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False),
I even added a watch for `arr` and found all hidden cells (filtered ones) are loaded correctly on the array. Did I misunderstood you !!

Comment: @Soma I'm afraid, you did not understood the point... It doesn't matter if the range is filtered or not, **if you use the whole range**! If you use the **visible cells of the filtered range**, trying to place it in an array, the array will contain **only its first area**.

Answer (score 3):

### Auto Filtering Using a Dictionary

**Arrays (Nit-Picking!?)**

- To ensure the `Array` function returns a zero-based array you better use the following (`VBA.`):

  ```
  filter_Criteria = VBA.Array("Cathodic Protection", "C.P", "Riser")
  ```
- If you don't want to do the previous, use the following (`LBound` (recommended by several top contributors)):

  ```
  For i = LBound(filter_Criteria) To UBound(filter_Criteria)
  ```
- The resulting array when using the `Split` function is always a 1D zero-based array of strings.

**Loops**

- Loops slow down the code. Whenever 'possible' (reasonable), you should avoid them. In time you will figure out when it is reasonable.
- In this particular case, it is a bit hard to see how to do it (see `When using an array...` in the continuation).

**Application.Match**

- When using a simple data type as the first parameter in `Application.Match`, the result will always be a number or an error value (Error 2042). Test the result with the following:

  ```
  If IsNumeric(Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0)) Then
  ```

  which is similar to what is presented in the first posted answer to this question.
- When using an array or a range as the first parameter in `Application.Match`, the result will always be a one-based array (1D or 2D) of numbers and/or error values. You can use `Application.Count` to count (or check for) the matches thus avoiding the loop and not being concerned about the initial part regarding the arrays:

  ```
  With Application
      If .Count(.Match(filter_Criteria, subStrings, 0)) > 0 Then
          If Not...
              '''
          End If
      End If 
  End With
  ```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and the error has disappeared , **But**, there is one criteria "`Cathodic Protection`" did not included on the result of AutoFilter, I know it has a space. Should I post a new question or it can be adapted on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a type mismatch in this line, caused by "Application.Match" not returning a bool.

```
If Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0) Then
```

So you need to rewrite it like this:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(filter_Criteria(i), subStrings, 0)) Then
```