# How to Loop all array elements on the same time?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I can not loop all the elements of array `filter_Criteria` on the same time ,
So I had to use three If conditions to check for my rule.
I need to **strip down** these three lines of my code:

```
 If InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(0)) = 0 And _
    InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(1)) = 0 And _
    InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(2)) = 0 Then
```

this is the code:

```
Sub Loop_Array_at_the_same_time()
    
    Dim filter_Criteria() As Variant, dict As Object, arr, r As Long
    
    filter_Criteria = Array("A", "B", "C")
    
    arr = Application.Transpose(Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
   
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
    
         If InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(0)) = 0 And _
            InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(1)) = 0 And _
            InStr(arr(r, 1), filter_Criteria(2)) = 0 Then
               
            dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString
                 
         End If
        
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credits of this working answer @FaneDuru

I should create a boolean variable which to be made as true during (the same) iteration, without `using dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString`.
Before the check I must have `boolFound = false`.
Then checking after iteration if the respective variable is false Then `dict(arr(r, 1)) = vbNullString`

```
Sub Loop_Array_at_the_same_time()
    
    Dim filter_Criteria() As Variant, dict As Object, arr, r As Long
    
    filter_Criteria = Array("*A*", "*B*", "*C*")
    
    arr = Application.Transpose(Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
   
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim boolFound As Boolean, el As Variant

    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
          boolFound = False
            For Each el In filter_Criteria
                If arr(r) Like el Then boolFound = True: Exit For
           Next el
           If Not boolFound Then dict(CStr(arr(r))) = vbNullString
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: there were two perfectly working answers, but you said you tested them and they didn't work. But then you post your own answer, which you obviously didn't test. Because if you did you'd noticed the mistake in your code. You are trying to reference a 1D array as a 2D array (which will lead to runtime Error 9). This error would have come up the moment you'd run the code the first time. So how is it you allegedly tested others' answers and found something wrong, but your own answer with apparent errors you didn't test.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII , the logic itself is working perfectly, anyhow I corrected the code and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Working off of the answer Ike gave: The suggestion of using `like` is good. However trying to convert the actual value into the pattern is kinda weird. You should rather create a pattern out of the values that stay the same (so in this case A, B and C) and compare that pattern against the values.

The pattern we create is the following. [A,B,C] This will match any of those characters, so if a String contains an A this part will match, if a string contains a B this part will match and so on. To account for all characters that might or might not come before or after the characters we are looking for, we just put a `*` in front and behind the pattern (* means 0 or more of any character (so basically matches anything, which is what we want))

```
Sub look_Array()

Dim filter_Criteria As String
filter_Criteria = "|*[" & Join(Array("A", "B", "C"), "") & "]*|"

Dim arrValues As Variant
arrValues = Application.Transpose(Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
   
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim r As Long

For r = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
    If Not "|" & arrValues(r) & "|" Like filter_Criteria Then
        dict(arrValues(r)) = vbNullString
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried and found `dict.Keys` is empty (count of keys=0)

Comment: @Soma what are the values you tried?

Comment: @Soma no Shit - but what are those Strings?. Like in write the strings so I can see what is going on. - Because I suspect you wanted a Case-Insensitive Search, but didn't specify this, because I tested the code and it works as expected - But I can only really tell what you want/are trying to do, if you share the values you are testing the code with.

Comment: Nice idea, but it works only for single characters... It happens I know (from a previous question) that he needs filtering strings of **many characters**. Unfortunately, his example in the question is not eloquent, I voted up the idea, solving the question **as it has been formulated**... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru no it works for multi-Char strings aswell. I tested it with: `caBe`  `lecm` `ZBE` `EFG` `ART` - the output was as you would expect: "lecm" and "EFG". What makes you think it would only work for single char-strings? - The * in our pattern basically solve this issue - and since our criteria are in an Or relationship, as soon as one is found it will match

Comment: I must confess I only tested the  next string (based on his previous question(s)) `filter_Criteria = "|*[" & Join(Array("Cathodic Protection", "C.P", "Riser"), ",") & "]*|"`. It returns false positive (`True`) for the next strings: `Debug.print "I" & "Data Validation Multi-Select Premium Kit" & "|" Like filter_Criteria`, also `"|" & "abcdefgh" & "|" like  filter_Criteria` and  `"|" & "a" & "|" like  filter_Criteria`.  I stopped testing. Only strings of a single digit being numeric returned 'False'... Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @FaneDuru oh multiple string criteria (I was thinking about multiple string values to test against) ... yeah that wouldn't work how the code currently stands. (But should be a fairly easy fix - you'd just need to construct the criteria as (non)-capturing groups. (assuming `like` supports that, otherwise I'd just switch to good old RegEx)

Comment: The answer (suggested by me on the previous question) also works and it is very fast. No need of any transposing. A 2D array can be iterated directly. He initially asked about a way to filter **by the array strings**, then to do it for not matching ones. The question can be solved with standard VBA without too much problems, I think... I am also afraid that a `RegEx` solution will be more complicated for the case in discussion, too... :) Please, see that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163529/autofilter-with-multiple-criteria-using-dictionary)...

Comment: In all honesty, the transposing is present in my answer, because it was present in the question - I am quite lazy (and just changed the parts that were in question - without looking at the other parts too much ...) - But yeah regarding plain VBA vs. RegEx; I must agree plain VBA is (especially in such a straight forward case) easier to understand. - I just usually default to RegEx, since my requrements get icreasingly more complicated over time (and imo RegEx is more flexible if you need to add/change stuff (for example Prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the filter values as one string - and then use the `like` operator:

```vb
Sub look_Array()

Dim filter_Criteria As String
filter_Criteria = "|" & Join(Array("A", "B", "C"), "|") & "|"

Dim arrValues As Variant
arrValues = Application.Transpose(Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
   
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim r As Long

For r = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
    If Not filter_Criteria Like "*|" & arrValues(r) & "|*" Then
        dict(arrValues(r)) = vbNullString
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

To be on the safe side, we need the pipe symbol on both sides of the strings.

Comment: All the cells of `column B:B` are added as keys of `dict` , which means there is something wrong on this answer. the expected `dict.keys` are the cells **not contain** any element of  `filter_Criteria`

Comment: why are you trying to use the value as a pattern? The part right of the Like Operator is the pattern. Trying to create a pattern out of the actual string we are trying to evaluate is weird. Why not creating a pattern out of the actual criteria (which in itself are already like a pattern)

Comment: For me it works: https://i.imgur.com/3nOdmGZ.png - I added a debug.print before adding to the dictionary. A, B, C are not added ... Please show your data - maybe there is a specialty that is not handled correct.